# vaadin: refreshing content after socket request

Tags: android, websocket, vaadin, vaadin7

i am new to vaadin and am writing a websocket client with it connected with a websocket server on android.

the client generates a list of all phone-contact-groups on the left side, ad after each click on this group, the client loads the assoziated contacst to the right side of the computer screen.

verything works fine so far, execpt that the loaded contacts dont appear after the first click on it, but only after the second. it loads always the groups clicked before the actual click. in the debugger i can see that the right contacts are already loaded to the layout, but still they only appear after the next click. it always shows the "old contacts" not the ones that where created with the current click. i need somehow to force the layout to refresh, but without success so far

none of the answers i found so far helped: neither to use setImmediate(true), on the conainer, nor requestRepaint(true);

```
 @Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

    layoutMain = new HorizontalLayout();
    setContent(layoutMain);

    layoutLeft = new VerticalLayout();
    layoutRight = new VerticalLayout();

    layoutMain.addComponent(layoutLeft);
    layoutMain.addComponent(layoutRight);

    final Client client;
    try {
        client = new Client(new URI("ws://192.168.0.14:8080"));
        Client.ClientListener clientListener = new Client.ClientListener() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                short httpStatus = serverHandshake.getHttpStatus();
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) { // getting a json string with the data needed to fill the layout
                try {
                    final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(message);
                    JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper(jsonObj);

                    if (jsonHelper.isEvent("selectGroups")) {
                        JSONArray list = jsonHelper.getList();

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonGroup = (JSONObject) list.get(i);
                            final Button button = new Button(jsonGroup.getString("id") + ": " + jsonGroup.getString("name"));
                            button.setData(jsonGroup.getString("id"));
                            button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                                    try {
                                        ... // generate a json object to send to the server
                                        client.send(jsonHelperClick.toString());
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            layoutLeft.addComponent(button); // adding the group as a button to the left side of the layout
                        }
                        // problem could be solved with push()
                        return;
                    }

                    if (jsonHelper.isEvent("availableContacts")) {
                        layoutRight.removeAllComponents();
                        JSONArray list = jsonHelper.getList(); // getting the list of all contacst from the phone
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonContact = (JSONObject) list.get(i);
                            HorizontalLayout rowContact = new HorizontalLayout();
                            ... // filling the row representing the contact
                            layoutRight.addComponent(rowContact); // adding a contactrow to the right side of the layout
                        }
                        // problem could be solved with push()

                        // at this point i already see the right data added to layoutRight, but at the end still the old data is shown, not the new one

                        // layoutRight.requestRepaint(true);
                        // layoutRight.setImmediate(true);
                        // layoutRight.beforeClientResponse(true);

                        // layoutMain.requestRepaint(true);
                        // layoutMain.setImmediate(true);
                        //layoutMain.beforeClientResponse(true);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    String message1 = e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        client.setClientListener(clientListener);
        client.connect();

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>at.richardlederer.RemoteSms</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- Enable server push -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>pushmode</param-name>
        <param-value>manual</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

EDIT:
i changed the pushmode to manual, so that the changes only happen when i cal the push() method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [enable server push](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html) in your vaadin application.

The onMessage callback handler is called later on, 
when the json data is received by the application.
This then updates the UI state on serverside.

When the next interaction on the browser side is done,
all server side updates are then sent to the browser.

Enabling it is simple:

```
@Push
public class PushyUI extends UI {
```

Comment: i tried this before but it did not help, actually i am using vaadin as a client (to replace the already well working javascript-client i programmed before) not as a server. anyway, its also not the problem that i dont receive the data at the right time. i get the json array with the information needed to generat the list, and the components are generated at the right time at the right place, as i can see in the debugger. the only problem is that those generated components dont have any effect on the screen. the screen only is updated after the next click.

Comment: The behaviour you are seeing is definitively related to the fact that the UI state is not yet "published" in the webbrowser. Is your app running without any servlet engine, directly native in the web browser?

Comment: sorry, i did not totally understand. i am only writing sockets since a few weeks. i wrote an android app that acts as websocket server (with tootallnate), and already wrote a javascript client, that was able to communicate with that android server perfectly and that can remote controll it. now i tried to do the same with vaadin and replace the javascript i wrote before.. i installed vaadin, and used again the tootallnate library to create a client to connect to my android phone and to controll it); i did not succeed with any other libarary so far. adding @Push did not help.

Comment: How are you running your vaadin app? From a IDE, or...?

Comment: i run it with IntelliJ, like i did with the javascript version.

Comment: So you are running your application from tomcat or similar engine. The JSON connector is running in async mode, you you will also have to respect the "11.16.3. Accessing UI from Another Thread" [link]https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html#advanced.push.running

Comment: to be honest, i did not expect it to be so complicated, because it was so easy to do it just with javascript. but anyway, you braught me a good idea. i just call push() right after i generated the right data, and now it works:-)!

Comment: btw. it now even works without @Push(), i dont even need to have the vaadin push library for it, the method push() did everything i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

calling the method push() after the components are filled solved the problem